# MobileFirst development server startup failure

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

I have just installed Eclipse Kepler (eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64) and installed MobileFirst V6.3 following installation instruction.  I am running on Windows 7.

My Eclipse is installed D:\Dev\Eclipse
My workspace is : E:\Work\WorkSpaces\Eclipse\EclipseTrainingWorklight
Java installation :  D:\Dev\Java    (versions 1.8)

Here is the log message :

> ******************************************************************************** product = WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.3
>   (wlp-1.0.6.cl50320140731-0257) wlp.install.dir =
>   D:/Dev/Eclipse/plugins/com.worklight.worklight-artifacts_6.3.0.00-20141127-1357/liberty/wlp/
>   server.config.dir =
>   E:/Work/WorkSpaces/Eclipse/EclipseTrainingWorklight/MobileFirstServerConfig/servers/worklight/
>   java.home = D:\Dev\Java\jre1.8 java.version = 1.8.0_20 java.runtime =
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (1.8.0_20-b26) os = Windows 7 (6.1;
>   amd64) (en_US)
>   ******************************************************************************** [12/17/14 15:41:07:955 EST] 00000001
>   com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.TraceSpecification               I
>   TRAS0018I: The trace state has been changed. The new trace state is
>   *=info. [12/17/14 15:41:07:975 EST] 00000001 com.ibm.ws.kernel.launch.internal.FrameworkManager           A
>   CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched. [12/17/14
>   15:41:08:754 EST] 00000013
>   ibm.ws.ras.instrument.internal.main.AlpineRuntimeTransformer E
>   TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class
>   javax/naming/spi/InitialContextFactoryBuilder with exception
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.ibm.ws.ras.instrument.internal.main.AlpineRuntimeTransformer.transform(AlpineRuntimeTransformer.java:276)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.ras.instrument.internal.main.AlpineRuntimeTransformer.transform(AlpineRuntimeTransformer.java:337)
>     at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SystemBundleLoader.findLocalClass(SystemBundleLoader.java:117)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:452)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>
> [12/17/14 15:41:08:826 EST] 00000013
>   ibm.ws.ras.instrument.internal.main.AlpineRuntimeTransformer E
>   TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class
>   java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet with exception
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.ibm.ws.ras.instrument.internal.main.AlpineRuntimeTransformer.transform(AlpineRuntimeTransformer.java:276)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.ras.instrument.internal.main.AlpineRuntimeTransformer.transform(AlpineRuntimeTransformer.java:337)
>     at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:420)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.ibm.ws.kernel.service.location.internal.SymbolRegistry.(SymbolRegistry.java:115)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.kernel.service.location.internal.SymbolRegistry.(SymbolRegistry.java:38)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.kernel.service.location.internal.WsLocationAdminImpl.createLocations(WsLocationAdminImpl.java:97)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.kernel.service.location.internal.Activator.start(Activator.java:53)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
>
> [12/17/14 15:41:08:828 EST] 00000013
>   ibm.ws.ras.instrument.internal.main.AlpineRuntimeTransformer E
>   TRAS0033E: Runtime injection of detailed method trace failed for class
>   java/util/NavigableSet with exception
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.ibm.ws.ras.instrument.internal.main.AlpineRuntimeTransformer.transform(AlpineRuntimeTransformer.java:276)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.ras.instrument.internal.main.AlpineRuntimeTransformer.transform(AlpineRuntimeTransformer.java:337)
>     at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.ibm.ws.kernel.internal.classloader.BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.loadClass(BootstrapChildFirstJarClassloader.java:56)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:420)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.ibm.ws.kernel.service.location.internal.SymbolRegistry.(SymbolRegistry.java:115)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.kernel.service.location.internal.SymbolRegistry.(SymbolRegistry.java:38)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.kernel.service.location.internal.WsLocationAdminImpl.createLocations(WsLocationAdminImpl.java:97)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.kernel.service.location.internal.Activator.start(Activator.java:53)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

Comment: what "installation instruction" did you follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Java 8. Worklight/MobileFirst Platform does not support Java 8.

Downgrade to either Java 6 or 7 and try again.
The Studio plug-in should then begin to work.